# How to enable Spring application context in servlets not managed by DispatcherServlet?

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

The scenario:

1. Some common beans are defined in context xml files.
2. DispatcherServlet is mapped to `/foo/*`.
3. MyServlet is mapped to `/bar/*`.
4. I want to share common beans between Foo classes and Bar classes.

The questions:

1. Can I get the ApplicationContext for the DispatcherServlet, from MyServlet? (In web.xml, I have defined MyServlet after the DispatcherServlet).
2. If Q1 is not, how can I get the ApplicationContext from MyServlet? Or, how can I let MyServlet be wired with a specific ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't share the context of one servlet with another, but you *can* declare a second context which acts as the parent context of the DispatcherServlet. Any beans which you need to access from both servlets should go into this new context.

See [section 3.13.4 of the Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create) for how to set this up.

Comment: Good reference. But I didn't get how to declare the parent context for DispatcherServlet, can you give me more detail?